# Using NSJSONSerialization with swift on ubuntu/linux

Tags: linux, swift, ubuntu, swift2

Is it possible to parse JSON using NSJSONSerialization when running swift on ubuntu? Since foundation is available I am assuming it should be?

If not, Is there any other way of serialising and deserialising JSON in swift on linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSJSONSerialization is partly implemented (serialization is not yet implemented)

do it yourself, in accordance with your needs, and you will see, that it is the best investment and great way to understand Swift and its possibilities. you can also use one of the opensource libraries available around. SwiftyJSON is very popular, for an example

As mentioned by Sebastian Osiński, unfortunately it use NSJSONSerialization too.

you can check this very simple, but working example [swift json](https://gist.github.com/op183/92263a22a5b44e32d57d). it is far away to be 'perfect', but as an inspiration it could help you, i hope so.

Comment: SwiftyJSON uses NSJSONSerialization under the hood, so it's not the solution here.

Comment: @SebastianOsiński thanks! I never use it, i am sorry.

Comment: Do you know if NSJSONSerialization is still only partly implemented? And where does one go to see which parts of the standard libraries are or are not yet implemented in Linux?

Answer (score 2):

I am using [TidyJSON](https://github.com/benloong/TidyJSON) for this, because it combines much of the ease of `SwiftyJSON` but does not rely on `NSJSONSerialization` for parsing. It works wherever Swift works, and I'm using it just fine in my current Swift/Ubuntu projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the server side Swift framework "Perfect", You can do something like this to convert "data" (Binary) type to "JSONConvertable" (Swift Arrays etc) object types.

```
do{
    let jsonObject = try String.init(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)?.jsonDecode()
    print("\(jsonObject as! [String])")
    }catch{
        response.completed(status: .badRequest)
        return
    }
```